# Is there a way to display the already added pictures when editing a post using Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, nested-forms

I am developing a web app where people can post new questions. Each question contains many sub-questions, and each sub-question can have many images. To post new questions, I use a Rails plug-in called 'nested-form', and to add pictures I use Paperclip.
Here is my question. When I add new questions, everything works fine. But when I edit the question, the fields for the pictures are still there but the picture directories in the fields are gone. If I submit the form with the blank fields, all the pictures would be gone. Therefore, I have to upload all the pictures again when I edit a question, even if I don't want to do any change to the pictures.
Here is my code:

new_question.html.erb:

```
<%= nested_form_for @question, :url => {:action => 'create_question'} do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name # some fields for @question %>
      <%= f.text_area :name %>

       <%= f.fields_for :subquestions do |builder| %>
       <%= render 'subquestion_fields', :f => builder %>
       <%= builder.link_to_remove 'Remove Sub-question' %>
```

_subquestion_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><br>
<%= f.link_to_add 'Add an image', :qimages %><br>


<%= f.fields_for :qimages,   :html => { :multipart => true } do |builder| %>
<%= render 'qimage_fields', :f => builder %>
<%= builder.link_to_remove 'Remove this image' %><br>


<% end %>
```

_qimage_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

edit_question.html.erb uses the same partials above, but the picture that are already added to the question are not displayed(leaving blank 'qimage' fields). Is there a way to display all the images when editing the question?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I just found out that there is a solution on Ryanb's Nested Form page. It is possible to track the event that generates new fields by listening to the `nested:fieldAdded` event, and the generated elements can be found by via `event.field`.